# adding sub totals to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame (df):

```
          Sales Tax
A1          109   8
A2          116  10
A3          104   7
A total       0   0
B1          110   9
B2          130   8
B total       0   0
C           113  16
D1          135  15
D2          110  16
D3          130  11
D4          151  17
D total       0   0
```

As you can see the sub total rows (e.g. `A Total`) do not have a totals for the rows of the data frame that they are associated with.  For example Sales for `A total` should be the sum of `Sales` for `A1`,`A2` and `A3` (109,116 and 104 summing to 329).

Is it possible to return the following:

```
        Sales   Tax
A1        109     8
A2        116    10
A3        104     7
A total   329    25
B1        110     9
B2        130     8
B total   240    17
C         113    16
D1        135    15
D2        110    16
D3        130    11
D4        151    17
D total   526    59
```

where any row with 'total' has the sub totals for their respective parts of the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the sum of all the groups, even the ones you might not use (like C) and then use the resulting data to update the original df.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sales': {'A1': 109,
  'A2': 116,
  'A3': 104,
  'A total': 0,
  'B1': 110,
  'B2': 130,
  'B total': 0,
  'C': 113,
  'D1': 135,
  'D2': 110,
  'D3': 130,
  'D4': 151,
  'D total': 0},
 'Tax': {'A1': 8,
  'A2': 10,
  'A3': 7,
  'A total': 0,
  'B1': 9,
  'B2': 8,
  'B total': 0,
  'C': 16,
  'D1': 15,
  'D2': 16,
  'D3': 11,
  'D4': 17,
  'D total': 0}})

t = df.groupby(df.index.str[0]).sum()
t.index += ' total'

df.update(t)

print(df)
```

Output

```
    Sales   Tax
A1       109.0   8.0
A2       116.0  10.0
A3       104.0   7.0
A total  329.0  25.0
B1       110.0   9.0
B2       130.0   8.0
B total  240.0  17.0
C        113.0  16.0
D1       135.0  15.0
D2       110.0  16.0
D3       130.0  11.0
D4       151.0  17.0
D total  526.0  59.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can form  the groups based on the total (each group ends with "total"), then compute the sum and replace with boolean indexing:

```
# which indices contain "total"?
mask = df.index.str.contains('total')
# form groups using a reverse cumsum
group = mask[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]
# update the total rows with the sum per group
df.loc[mask] = df.groupby(group).transform('sum').loc[mask]
```

output:

```
         Sales  Tax
A1         109    8
A2         116   10
A3         104    7
A total    329   25
B1         110    9
B2         130    8
B total    240   17
C          113   16
D1         135   15
D2         110   16
D3         130   11
D4         151   17
D total    639   75
```